# Can a form (loaded from a page with AJAX) be submitted using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am working on a userscript for an internal website (witten ASP.NET WebForms, I believe). I am trying to automate some things and what I would like to accomplish is load a page via AJAX and then submit a form on this page using AJAX. The form has multiple submit buttons and I want to perform the equivalent action of clicking one of these buttons. Below is a simplified version of what I am using at the moment. It doesn't seem to work (the action that would have been performed if I had loaded the page and clicked the button normally did not occur) and I'm not sure if I've perhaps made a mistake.

```
fetch(URL, {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
}).then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
    const form = doc.getElementById('Form1');
    const button = doc.getElementById('uc_btnDelete');
    const data = new FormData(form);
    data.set(button.name, button.value); //submit the form as if uc_btnDelete was clicked
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: data,
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    }).then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
        //success
    });
});
```

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work". What doesn't happen that you expect to happen? What happens that you don't expect? Please read [ask].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The action that would have been performed if I had loaded the page and clicked the button normally did not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question it appears that the issue was with the referring URL not being what the server was expecting. I think that `window.history.replaceState()` is my solution to this.